# Wrong moving speed for sprite animation

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I'm using Math.atan2 method to detect two different points from point a to point b.

But my sprite animation will be moving at a super fast speed when it detect the other point. Is it possible to reduce the moving speed of my sprite animation?

So after you press on the add fish button, a fish sprite animation will be moving on the canvas. Then you can click on any part of the canvas, and the fish sprite animation will be moving towards it. At the same time you will be seeing the super fast moving speed sprite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to change the speed mechanism of the fish, By lowering the number you multiply with
changing

```
this.speedX= (tx/dist) * 1
```

into

```
this.speedX=(tx/dist) * 0.1
```

should reduce the speed by 10 times